# adding curves to images already in a javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, image

Id like to add curved edges to these images that I have already in a javascript.

```
var howOften = 5; //number often in seconds to rotate
var current = 0; //start the counter at 0
var ns6 = document.getElementById&&!document.all; //detect netscape 6

// place your images, text, etc in the array elements here
var items = new Array();

items[0]="<a href='link.htm' ><img alt='Corinthians match'src='../images/1sts/1sts_corithas.jpg' width='300' height='184' border='0' /></a>"; //a linked image
items[1]="<a href='link.htm'><img alt='Ago playing' src='../images/1sts/ago_1sts.jpg' width='300' height='184' border='0' /></a>"; //a linked image
items[2]="<a href='link.htm'><img alt='Celebration' src='../images/1sts/annadale_goal_final.jpg' width='300' height='184' border='0' /></a>"; //a linked image
items[3]="<a href='link.htm'><img alt='Defender' src='../images/1sts/defender_1sts.jpg' width='300' height='184'' border='0' /></a>"; //a linked image
items[4]="<a href='link.htm'><img alt='kirk club medal' src='../images/1sts/kirk_cup_medal.jpg' width='300' height='184' border='0' /></a>"; //a linked image

function rotater1() {
document.getElementById("placeholder").innerHTML = items[current];
current = (current==items.length-1) ? 0 : current + 1;
setTimeout("rotater()",howOften*1000);
}

function rotater() {
if(document.layers) {
    document.placeholderlayer.document.write(items[current]);
    document.placeholderlayer.document.close();
}
if(ns6)document.getElementById("placeholderdiv").innerHTML=items[current]
    if(document.all)
        placeholderdiv.innerHTML=items[current];

current = (current==items.length-1) ? 0 : current + 1; //increment or reset
setTimeout("rotater()",howOften*1000);
}
```

Im not sure how to add it in without breaking the code

Comment: `//detect netscape 6` I don't think you really have to worry about that anymore...

Comment: What do you mean by "curved edges"? Rounded corners, or beveling?

Comment: Got it sorted thanks, I wasnt sure how to make the border-radius work with the image in js.

Answer (score 0):

I'd strongly advise to style the rounded corners using `css` (if that's what you mean by curves), rather than javascript.
For every item, add a `css` class, let's say `rounded-corners`. Then, in a `css` file add this rule:

```
.rounded-corners {
    border-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
}
```

Taking as an example items[0], it would become:

```
items[0]="<a href='link.htm' ><img class='rounded-corners' alt='Corinthians match'src='../images/1sts/1sts_corithas.jpg' width='300' height='184' border='0' /></a>";
```